# how to limit a gitlab runner to running only one job concurrently?

Tags: gitlab, cicd

I want to limit a GitLab Runner to running only one job concurrently under linux.

I already modified the file called config.toml like this below:

```
concurrent=1
......

[[runner]]
  limit=1
  ......
```

but it didn't work. The runner still can run more than one job concurrently.

Comment: How do you know there is more than one job running? Could it be the jobs are running on other runners?